# Showing a Modal view

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my application, I need to show two Modal view one after the other. Tap on one screen will show a Modal and then a button on this Modal view will show another Modal.

Both my Modal view also contains a top bar with two buttons.

What is the best way to showing these Modal views. Should I use Navigation controller to control these Modal views or a simple view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just have them set up using a view controller.  Just do this to present the view when it's needed, and just implement a "Done" or "Save" UIBarButton depending on what you need it for.

```
YourViewController *yourView = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
yourView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:yourView animated:YES];
```

Comment: a small note, you should change YourView to YourViewController